# Invalid source: undefined when I am creating new project, using "ng new mynewProject"

Tags: angular

[image]

Invalid source: undefined when I am creating new project, using "ng new mynewProject"

Comment: Those are console errors, post them as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're still using a release candidate version locally while your global version is pretty much up to date, try this:

`npm install @angular/cli`

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have already did this same and same issue